# the operator @"%@ ==[c] %@" seems not supported on Leopard. What should I use then?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

the operator `==[c]` like in `@"%@ ==[c] %@"` seems not supported on Leopard.

What operator should I use to compare strings with different casing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this will work: `@"%@ LIKE[c] %@"`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try calling

```
- (NSComparisonResult)caseInsensitiveCompare:(NSString *)aString
```

Or another method might be using

```
[[string1 lowercaseString] isEqualToString:[string2 lowercaseString]];
```

Answer (score 0):

If the left hand side of the comparison is a property name then you need to use the [%K specifier](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001793-210173).

```
@"%K ==[c] %@"
```